# Find the probability of one expression

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Could you please help me to calculate the probability as follows
\begin{align}
   \rho=\mathsf{Pr}\left\{\frac{X_1}{X_2} >\frac{Y_1+a}{Y_2 + a}\right\}
\end{align}
where $X_1,X_2, Y_2$, and $Y_2$ are independent exponential distributed random variables with mean $\Omega_{X_1}, \Omega_{X_2}, \Omega_{Y_1}$, and $\Omega_{Y_2}$, respectively and $a$ is a positive constant.

Comment: What are your attempts? I would also suggest you to use another notation for means, otherwise integrals will be messy.

Comment: Many thanks Ilya for your comment. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will change the notations. Let $\mu_k = \mathsf{E}(X_k)$ and $\lambda_k = \mathsf{E}(Y_k)$ for $k=0, 1$.

**Lemma 1**. For $\alpha > 0$, $\mathsf{Pr}\left( X_1 > X_2 \alpha \right) = \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_1 + \alpha \mu_2}$.
**Proof:**
$$
 \mathsf{Pr}(X_1 > \alpha X_2) = \mathsf{E}\left( \mathsf{Pr}(X_1 > \alpha X_2 |X_2) \right) = \mathsf{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\alpha}{\mu_1} X_2}\right)
$$
The latter is the moment generating function of $X_2$ at $t=\frac{\alpha}{\mu_1}$, yielding the result.  $\square$

**Lemma 2.** $\mathsf{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-t Y_k}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + t \lambda_k}$.
**Proof:**
$$
   \mathsf{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-t Y_k}\right) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda_k} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x}{\lambda_k}} \mathrm{e}^{-t x} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{\lambda_k}\frac{1}{t+ \frac{1}{\lambda_k}} = \frac{1}{1+t \lambda_k} .\quad \square
$$

Now:
$$
  \mathsf{Pr}\left( \frac{X_1}{X_2} > \frac{Y_1+a}{Y_2+a} \right) = \mathsf{E}\left( \mathsf{Pr}\left( \left. X_1 > X_2 \frac{Y_1+a}{Y_2+a} \right| Y_1, Y_2 \right) \right) \stackrel{\text{Lemma 1}}{=} \mathsf{E}\left( \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_1 + \mu_2 \frac{Y_1+a}{Y_2+a} } \right)
$$
The latter expectation can be evaluated using $\frac{1}{x} = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x t} \mathrm{d} t$:
$$
 \mathsf{E}\left( \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_1 + \mu_2 \frac{Y_1+a}{Y_2+a} } \right) = 
 \mathsf{E}\left( \frac{\mu_1 (Y_2+a)}{\mu_1 (Y_2+a) + \mu_2 (Y_1+a)} \right) = \int_0^\infty \mathsf{E} \left( \mu_1 (Y_2+a) \mathrm{e}^{- t (\mu_1 (Y_2+a) + \mu_2 (Y_1+a))}  \right)\mathrm{d} t
$$
The expectation under the integral sign is easy to evaluate using:
$$
   \mathsf{E} \left( \mu_1 (Y_2+a) \mathrm{e}^{- t (\mu_1 (Y_2+a) + \mu_2 (Y_1+a))}  \right) = -\left. \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s} \mathsf{E} \left( \mathrm{e}^{- s \mu_1 (Y_2+a) - t \mu_2 (Y_1+a))}  \right) \right|_{s=t} \stackrel{\text{indep.}}{=} -\left. \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s} \mathsf{E} \left( \mathrm{e}^{- s \mu_1 (Y_2+a)} \right) \mathsf{E} \left( \mathrm{e}^{- t \mu_2 (Y_1+a))}  \right) \right|_{s=t} 
$$
Now using Lemma 2, 
$$
 \mathsf{E} \left( \mu_1 (Y_2+a) \mathrm{e}^{- t (\mu_1 (Y_2+a) + \mu_2 (Y_1+a))}  \right) = -\left. \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s} \left(\mathrm{e}^{- s \mu_1 a - t \mu_2 a} \frac{1}{1 + s \mu_1  \lambda_2}  \frac{1}{1 + t \mu_2 \lambda_1} \right)  \right|_{s=t} = \mathrm{e}^{-a t (\mu_1 + \mu_2)} \frac{\mu_1 ( a +\lambda_2 + a t \lambda_2 \mu_1)}{ (1 + t \lambda_1 \mu_2 )( 1 + t \lambda_2 \mu_1)^2}
$$
It now remains to evaluate the integral with respect to $t$:
$$
 \mathsf{Pr}\left( \frac{X_1}{X_2} > \frac{Y_1+a}{Y_2+a} \right) = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-a t (\mu_1 + \mu_2)} \frac{\mu_1 ( a +\lambda_2 + a t \lambda_2 \mu_1)}{ (1 + t \lambda_1 \mu_2 )( 1 + t \lambda_2 \mu_1)^2} \mathrm{d} t
$$
The result  involves [exponential integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral): 
$$
  \mathsf{Pr}\left( \frac{X_1}{X_2} > \frac{Y_1+a}{Y_2+a} \right) = \frac{\mu_2 \left(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \mu_1 + a \left(\lambda_2 \mu_1 - \lambda_1 \mu_2\right)\right)}{(\lambda_1 \mu_2 - \lambda_2 \mu_1)^2} f \left( \frac{a\left(\mu_1+\mu_2\right)}{\mu_1 \lambda_2} \right) -
\frac{\mu_1 \left(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \mu_2 + a \left(\lambda_1 \mu_2- \lambda_2 \mu_1\right)\right)}{(\lambda_1 \mu_2 - \lambda_2 \mu_1)^2} f \left( \frac{a\left(\mu_1+\mu_2\right)}{\mu_2 \lambda_1} \right) + \frac{\lambda_2 \mu_1}{\lambda_2 \mu_1 - \mu_2 \lambda_1}
$$
where $f(x) = \exp(x) \operatorname{Ei}(-x)$.
The result can be obtained in a symbolic computer algebra systems, like *Mathematica*. The result can be obtained by using the partial fraction decomposition for the rational factor of the integrand. Here is the result, with verification by Monte-Carlo and by quadratures:
[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your precious help! Sasha!